# Simplify an expression to show equivalence

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, mathematica

I am trying to simplify the following expression I have encountered in a book

$\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
K\\
k+1
\end{array}\right)x^{k+1}(1-x)^{K-1-k}$

and according to the book, it can be simplified to this:

$1-(1-x)^{K}$

I wonder how is it done? I've tried to use Mathematica (to which I am new) to verify, by using

$\text{Simplify}\left[\sum _{k=0}^{K-1} \left(\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 K \\
 k+1
\end{array}
\right)*x{}^{\wedge}(k+1)*(1-x){}^{\wedge}(K-1-k)\right)\right]$

and Mathematica returns

$\left\{\left\{-\frac{K q \left((1-q)^K-q^K\right)}{-1+2 q}\right\},\left\{-\frac{q \left(-(1-q)^K+(1-q)^K q+(1+K) q^K-(1+2 K) q^{1+K}\right)}{(1-2 q)^2}\right\}\right\}$

which I cannot quite make sense of it.

To sum up, my question is two-part:

1. how is the first expression equivalent to the second?
2. how should I interpret the result returned by Mathematica, presuming I'm doing the right thing to simplify the original formula?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\binom{K}{k+1}x^{k+1}(1-x)^{K-1-k}
&=\sum_{k=1}^{K}\binom{K}{k}x^{k}(1-x)^{K-k}\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{K}\binom{K}{k}x^{k}(1-x)^{K-k}\right)-(1-x)^K\\
&=(x+(1-x))^K-(1-x)^K\\
&=1^K-(1-x)^K
\end{align}
$$

Comment: thanks robjohn! So what is that thing returned by Mathematica then?

Comment: $K$ seems to be reserved (note its color is black, not blue). When using $K1$, Mathematica gives $\left(\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^{\text{K1}}-1\right) (1-x)^{\text{K1}}$.

Comment: thanks! but i still get some output like before, this is what I input in Mathematica: $\text{Simplify}\left[\sum _{k=0}^{n-1} \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 n \\
 k+1
\end{array}
\right)*x{}^{\wedge}(k+1)*(1-x){}^{\wedge}(n-1-k)\right]$, changing $K$ to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

`Simplify[PowerExpand[Simplify[Sum[Binomial[K, k + 1]*x^(k + 1)*(1 - x)^(K - k - 1), {k, 0, K - 1}], K > 0]]]` works nicely. The key is in the use of the second argument of `Simplify[]` to add assumptions about a variable. and using `PowerExpand[]` to distribute powers.

Comment: thanks J.M. I've tried yours in Mathematica and indeed it gives nice result. However, as soon as I replace your style of the expression with symbolic one, the problem persists. I used the following: $\text{Simplify}\left[\text{PowerExpand}\left[\text{Simplify}\left[\sum _{k=0}^{K-1} \left(\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 K \\
 k+1
\end{array}
\right)*(x{}^{\wedge}(k+1))*(1-x){}^{\wedge}(K-1-k)\right),K>0\right]\right]\right]$. Do you know why?

Comment: If I really want things to work in *Mathematica*, I often forgo the fancy formatting. Why do you need the fancy formatting here?

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the Binomial Formula, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. i see that in robjohn's answer too.

Comment: wish I could up-vote this but apparently i need 15 points of reputation. still much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer makes sense only with some background in probability.
Suppose first that $0 \le x\le 1$.

A possibly biased coin has probability $x$ of landing "heads."  Toss the coin $K$ times.  We compute the probability $P$ of **one or more** heads in two different ways.

The probability we get exactly $k+1$ heads is 
$$\binom{K}{k+1}x^{k+1}(1-x)^{K-1-k}.$$
Add up, from $k=0$ to $k=K-1$. We get the probability of $1$ head, plus the probability of $2$ heads, plus the probability of $3$ heads, and so on, up to the probability of $K$ heads.  Thus 
$$P=\sum_{k=0}^{K-1}\binom{K}{k+1}x^{k+1}(1-x)^{K-1-k}.$$

The probability of $0$ heads (all tails) is $(1-x)^K$, so the probability of one or more heads is $1-(1-x)^K$, and therefore 
$$P=1-(1-x)^K.$$

The argument so far only proves the desired result for $0\le x\le 1$. But note that for any $K$, each of the expressions we are trying to prove equal is a *polynomial* of degree $K$.  But if two polynomials $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ with real coefficients, each of degree $\le K$, are equal at $K+1$ values of $x$, then they are identically equal.